# Why Noether current gives the Schrödinger equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, conservation-laws, schroedinger-equation, noethers-theorem

Consider the Lagrangian density

$$
\mathcal{L} = i\Psi^\dagger\partial_0\Psi - \frac{1}{2m}\nabla\Psi^\dagger\cdot\nabla\Psi.
$$

If I want to calculate the Noether current

$$
\partial_\mu(\Pi^\mu D\Psi - W^\mu) = 0,
$$

under $U(1)$ symmetry of the fields $\Psi\rightarrow e^{i\alpha}\Psi$, $\Psi^\dagger\rightarrow e^{-i\alpha}\Psi^\dagger$, then for $\Psi$,

$$
D\Psi = i,
$$

and

$$
\Pi^0_\Psi = i\Psi^\dagger, \Pi^i_\Psi = \frac{1}{2m}\partial_i\Psi^\dagger, W^\mu = 0,
$$

we end up with

$$
-\partial_0\Psi^\dagger - \frac{i}{2m}\partial_i^2\Psi^\dagger=0.
$$

Similarly

$$
-\partial_0\Psi + \frac{i}{2m}\partial_i^2\Psi=0.
$$

My question is, why do I end with Schrödinger-like equations and not with the typical  $\partial_0\rho + \nabla\cdot j = 0$?

Did I messed up in the calculation?

Answer (score 2):

Define $\rho = \Psi$, $j = - \frac{i} {2m} \nabla \Psi$, then the equation is in the form you state.

Comment: Ty. Question, why in this case e.g. $\rho = \Psi^\dagger \Psi$ (as is the case in non-relativistic QM)?